# PHP - Get key name of array value

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I have an array as the following:

```
function example() {
    /* some stuff here that pushes items with
        dynamically created key strings into an array */

    return array( // now lets pretend it returns the created array
        'firstStringName' => $whatEver,
        'secondStringName' => $somethingElse
    );
}

$arr = example();

// now I know that $arr contains $arr['firstStringName'];
```

I need to find out the index of `$arr['firstStringName']` so that I am able to loop through `array_keys($arr)` and return the key string `'firstStringName'` by its index. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate with a use case of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 457, accepted):

If you have a value and want to find the key, use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) like this:

```
$arr = array ('first' => 'a', 'second' => 'b', );
$key = array_search ('a', $arr);
```

`$key` will now contain the key for value `'a'` (that is, `'first'`).

Comment: `array_filter()` can be used if you need to return all matching results instead of just the first matching one, as it preserves keys.

Comment: Something I think worth noting here: this solution was not working for me, until I discovered that sorting the array (sort($arr)) removes the key names, and resorts to the default 0,1,2,etc index values.  So if you're sorting, use asort (asort($arr)).  This maintains the key values.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: What if the values aren't unique?

Comment: @SimonRoberts Documentation solves your answer: returns the first corresponding key

Answer (score 83):

```
key($arr);
```

will return the key value for the current array element

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge This will return only what the internal pointer is currently "pointed at". If we need another reference, then we should use zrvans method, which hunts down the requested value, specifically.

Comment: @Parapluie is right, I used this to my advantage, I only needed the first key which is the default position for the array pointer.  You can use  `reset($array)` to reset the pointer to the beginning if you need.

Answer (score 55):

If i understand correctly, can't you simply use:

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
  echo $key;
}
```

See [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: I think he is looking for array_search php function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 27):

Here is another option

```
$array = [1=>'one', 2=>'two', 3=>'there'];
$array = array_flip($array);
echo $array['one'];
```

Answer (score 26):

If the name's dynamic, then you must have something like

```
$arr[$key]
```

which'd mean that $key contains the value of the key.

You can use `array_keys()` to get ALL the keys of an array, e.g.

```
$arr = array('a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd')
$x = array_keys($arr);
```

would give you

```
$x = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'c');
```

Answer (score 21):

Yes you can infact php is one of the few languages who provide such support..

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{

}
```

Comment: This is not relevant answer as per search and more time consuming.. Less effective coding

Answer (score 16):

if you need to return an array elements with same value, use `array_keys()` function

```
$array = array('red' => 1, 'blue' => 1, 'green' => 2);
print_r(array_keys($array, 1));
```

Answer (score 13):

use `array_keys()` to get an array of all the unique keys.

Note that an array with named keys like your `$arr` can also be accessed with numeric indexes, like `$arr[0]`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 8):

you can use key function of php to get the key name:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
    'fruit1' => 'apple',
    'fruit2' => 'orange',
    'fruit3' => 'grape',
    'fruit4' => 'apple',
    'fruit5' => 'apple');

    // this cycle echoes all associative array
    // key where value equals "apple"
    while ($fruit_name = current($array)) {
      if ($fruit_name == 'apple') {
        echo key($array).'<br />';
      }
    next($array);
     }
?>
```

like here : [PHP:key - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)