# How to find a key of array whose elements match elements of other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$shraniKastomFildove` like this:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "hashed_token" [1]=> string(17) "registration_time" [2]=> string(12) "noviCustmDev" [3]=> string(2) "no" }
```

And an array `$namesOfCustomFieldsUserWatsToUpdate` like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "noviCustmDev" }
```

I want to find index of matching element in `$shraniKastomFildove`. In this case it would be 2, since under index of 2 element with "noviCustmDev" value is stored.

Here is how I tried to get it:

```
foreach($namesOfCustomFieldsUserWatsToUpdate as $nesto){
    foreach($shraniKastomFildove as $dF){
       if($dF==$nesto){
           var_dump(key($shraniKastomFildove));
       }
     }
 }
```

But here it dumps number 3. I'm wondering is there a better and more efficient way to get exact value, 2 in this case, or is it due to `key()` counting indexes for 1 and not from 0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Get key name of array value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729410/php-get-key-name-of-array-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function to search for a value in an array.

This method returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, `FALSE` otherwise.

So your code will be like this:

```
foreach($namesOfCustomFieldsUserWatsToUpdate as $nesto){
    $key = array_search($nesto, $shraniKastomFildove);
    var_dump($key);
 }
```

Comment: great, solved it.. i tried already on my own with array_search but from some reason it didn't work as expected